# Check AD Computer Names against CSV file

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to write a Powershell script that will import a list of computer names from a CSV file and compare it against all computer names in AD. I need it to output a list of names from the CSV file that do not exist in AD.

I have been playing around with these commands but they don't do exactly what I want.

```
$import = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\username\Desktop\test.csv
$AD-Names = Get-ADComputer -filter * | Select -Expand Name
Compare-Object $import $AD-Names
```

This seems to give me a list of everything different from both variables which is an extremely long list. I really just need to know which computer names in the CSV file are not in AD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply compare the names from your CSV against the list of names from AD (I'm going to assume that the column title of the CSV is `Name`):

```
$ADNames = Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Select-Object -Expand Name
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\input.csv' |
    Where-Object { $ADNames -notcontains $_.Name } |
    Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\not_in_AD.csv' -NoType
```

---

Side note: `$AD-Names` is not a valid variable name. Change the hyphen to an underscore or remove it entirely, or put the variable name in curly brackets (`${AD-Names}`).

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, why do you need a csv file if there are only computer names ?
CSV files are usually used to store a table in a simple text file.

If your CSV only contains the computer names, and you only want to check for computer names, this could work for you :

```
$OutputComputers = @();
$InputComputers = Import-Csv input.csv -Header ComputerName;
$AdComputers = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "*"';


$InputComputers | ForEach-Object {$i = 0} { 
    if ($_.ComputerName -notin $AdComputers.Name) {
        $OutputComputers += New-Object PsObject -property @{
            'ComputerName' = $_.ComputerName
        }
    }
}

$OutputComputers | Export-Csv output.csv -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8 -Force  -NoTypeInformation
```

Hope it helps.